# Imacro javascript extracting and removing unwanted text

Tags: javascript, imacros

The is the code i want to extract:

```
<*span class='updated'>This user has a bodyguard named <a href='viewprofile.php?username=Username'><b*>Username<*b><*a>!
You must kill them before you can kill <* href='viewprofile.php?username=Username2'><*b>Username2<*b><*a>!<*span>
```

To extract this i use this following code:

```
macro_var+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:updated EXTRACT=TXT\n";
```

Which extracts this:

```
This user has a bodyguard namedThis user has a bodyguard namedThis user has a bodyguard namedusername!
You must kill them before you can killThis user has a bodyguard namedThis user has a bodyguard namedThis user has a bodyguard namedusername!
You must kill them before you can killThis user has a bodyguard namedThis user has a bodyguard namedThis user has a bodyguard namedusername!
You must kill them before you can killusername2!
```

What i want to be extracted is just "username" in the middle of the <*b><*/b>

Answer (score 0):

The 'XPATH' expression probably may help you:

```
macro_var+='TAG XPATH="//span[@class=\'updated\'][1]/a[1]" EXTRACT=TXT\n';
```